# NSOperationQueues are not executing concurrently

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am using `NSOperationQueues` in my application for downloading the data from the API and inserting into the local database. I am using one custom `NSOpertion` and adding to the `NSOpertionQueue` and executing for every request. When I perform two multiple requests with two different `NSOperationQueues`, they are not executing concurrently. I want know how to execute `NSOperationQueues` concurrently.

```
 //Request for master tables data.
  [RequestHandler getRequestForMasterTablesData:self];
  [RequestHandler postProspectListRequest:self];

/**
 * @brief ProspectList API: Gives the list of Prospects.
 */
+ (void)postProspectListRequest:(UIViewController*)lViewController {
    __weak ProspectListViewController *weakSelf = (ProspectListViewController*)lViewController;

    /**********************ONLINE MODE**********************/
    if ([self isNetworkAvailable]) {
        NSString *prospectListUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@",[[DataBaseManipulator sharedInstance] getCompanyURLFromUserDefaults],PROSPECTS,PROSPECTSLIST];
           RequestOperationManager *op = [[RequestOperationManager alloc] initWithGetRequest:prospectListUrl];
        __weak RequestOperationManager *weakOperation = op;
        op.completionBlock = ^{
            __strong RequestOperationManager *strong = weakOperation;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[DataBaseManipulator sharedInstance] insertDataIntoProspectListDB:[strong.resultsDictionary valueForKey:@"prospects"]];
            });
        };
        NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
        [networkQueue addOperation:op];
    }
}

+ (void)getRequestForMasterTablesData:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if (![self isNetworkAvailable]) {
        [[NetworkMonitor instance]displayNetworkMonitorAlert];
        return;
    }
    NSString *masterTablesUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[DataBaseManipulator sharedInstance] getCompanyURLFromUserDefaults],MASTERTABLESDATA];
   __weak LoginViewController *weakSelf = (LoginViewController*)viewController;
    [[GenricUI instance] createLoadView];
    RequestOperationManager *op = [[RequestOperationManager alloc] initWithGetRequest:masterTablesUrl];
    __weak RequestOperationManager *weakOperation = op;
    op.completionBlock = ^{
        __strong RequestOperationManager *strong = weakOperation;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[DataBaseManipulator sharedInstance] insertMasterDataIntoSalesItemTable:strong.resultsDictionary];
             [[GenricUI instance] removeLoadView];
            [weakSelf parseMasterTableResponse:strong.resultsDictionary];
        });
    };
    NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [networkQueue addOperation:op];
}
```

Iam calling the above two methods at a time but they are not executing concurrently. How to execute the above two methods concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want concurrent execution, you shouldn't have a call

```
[networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

On the other hand, this code

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[networkQueue addOperation:op];
```

is rather useless. You have a queue, add a single operation, and that's it. This doesn't achieve *anything*. If you want concurrent execution, create only *one* NSOperationQueue, keep hold of it to reuse it, and don't disable concurrent operations on it.

By the way, you seem to assume that once you have a network connection, a call to your server will succeed. That is to say the least rather optimistic.

Comment: Do you want me to remove [networkQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; this and make NSOperationQueue *networkQueue as global variable

Comment: @gnasher729 is right, if you set the number of concurrent operation to 1, only one operation will be executed at time. Furthermore creating a queue fora each operation doesn't make any sense at me. You should create just one operation queue and add operations to it.

Comment: @SudhakarTharigoppula: I don't want you to do anything, it's up to you what you do. But you should read the documentation of NSOperationQueue, read what setMaxConcurrentOperationCount does, and draw your conclusions.

Comment: I have done as you said, but I observed that they are not executing concurrently when I add NSOperations to NSOperationQueue I have done this by using isConcurrent method. Can you suggest me if the NSOperation is not executing concurrently, How do I reschedule it again.